# Passing arguments to dependency eclipse plugins when using mvn-tycho

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin

I am trying to write unit test cases for an eclipse plugin. Went through http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#run-the-build-with-the-tests and created a eclipse-test-plugin.

So, the test plugin (let's call is plugin-b) has a dependency on another plugin for which the test is written (plugin-a). 
When I run mvn clean install, I can see that tycho-surefire is trying to run the tests and in the process is trying to launch plugin-a. However, plugin-a requires a set of VM args to start correctly. Am trying to pass the arguments like below:
mvn -Dabc.properties=bridge\bundles\com.blah.blah.blah.blah.bridge\abc.properties clean install

but they aren't going through to plugin-a.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out:

mvn clean install -Dtycho.testArgLine="-Dabc.properties=../../bundles/com.blah.blah.blah.blah.bridge/abc.properties"

That'll pass the system properties to the test runtime.

Comment: This is the right option to use when setting system properties for the forked test VM from the command line (using `-D`). You can, however, also keep your system properties directly in the POM; simply add a [`<systemProperties>` element](https://eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#systemProperties) to the `<configuration>` of the `tycho-surefire-plugin`.